# Spring MVC: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'marks' available as request attribute. Tried all solutions

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-mvc

I tried all the solutions but I keep getting this error. Moreover if i don't use form:form in jsp file and use a simple HTML, I get the desired output.

Controller Class

```
@Controller
public class controller_class {

    /*
     * @RequestMapping(path = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET) public
     * ModelAndView mar() { return new ModelAndView("index","command",new marks());
     * }
     */
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public ModelAndView showComments() {
        return new ModelAndView("marks","command",new marks());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addMarks", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView stud(@ModelAttribute("marks") marks m) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("result");
        int k = m.calculate();
        mv.addObject("tot_marks", k);
        return mv;
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<form:form method = "POST" modelAttribute="marks" action = "/springmvc_qa3/addMarks">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td><form:label path = "sci_marks">Name</form:label></td>
               <td><form:input path = "sci_marks" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><form:label path = "maths_marks">Age</form:label></td>
               <td><form:input path = "maths_marks" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><form:label path = "eng_marks">id</form:label></td>
               <td><form:input path = "eng_marks" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan = "2">
                  <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>  
      </form:form>
   </body>
```

Correct Output if I use this instead

```
<form method="POST" action="/springmvc_qa3/addMarks"  >
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td><label >Science Marks</label></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="sci_marks" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><label >Mathematics Marks</label></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="maths_marks" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><label >English Marks</label></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="eng_marks" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="2">
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>  
      </form>
```

What is the reason that I can't get the right output using the first method?

Comment: In your index controller you are passing the object ‘new marks()’ under the name of ‘command’. But in the form you are using the object with the name marks. Btw please name your classes with capital first letter as in public class Marks {} and then declare variables with as Marks m.

Comment: So what changes should I incorporate in the code? And yes, you are right. I'll take care to name classes with capital first letter.

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your controller class:

```
@ModelAttribute("marks")
public Marks nameOfMethodDoesntMatter(){
    return new Marks();
}
```

make sure your Marks class has getters, setters and default constructor.

consider calling your class MarksDTO or something similar to convey its meaning better (DTO = data transfer object).